# Baudline : $\tt stdin$ is very slow

Tags: python

I built a radar system with two radars each with I/Q channels. I wrote a nice python script to read in the data from the serial port. The data is interleaved like so:

```
2.4,2.5,2.3,2.7,
2.2,2.1,2.9,3.1,
...
```

The python code is:

```
import serial
import binascii
import struct
#import sys

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-FTT86COK', 9600, bytesize=8, timeout=None)
data_in=ser.read(1)
for x in range(0, 50000):
    while (data_in!=b'\x2A'):
        data_in = ser.read(1)
    data_in = ser.read(80);
    d = struct.unpack('<HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH', data_in)
    i=0
    for i in range(0,10):
        j=i*4
        print str((d[j]/4096.0*5.0)) + ',' 
        print str((d[j+1]-4096)/4096.0*5.0) + ','
        print str(d[j+2]/4096.0*5.0) + ','
        print str((d[j+3]-4096)/4096.0*5.0) + ','
```

I then pipe this data to a tool called [baudline](http://www.baudline.com).

```
python sensor_in.py | /Applications/baudline.app/Contents/Resources/baudline -reset -samplerate 96000 -channels 4 -quadrature -stdin
```

For some reason the baudline tool updates very slowly and I can't see the signal in "real time". It might be my sample rate but I have played around with this number and I get the same result. I don't know how to get my sample rate, but I don't think this is the problem or main problem.

I also tried writing to a file and reading in from baud line but same result.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Python could be buffering stdout so that it does not write to it until a write buffer is full. Try sys.stdout.flush() after the print statements.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Thanks this does make the baudline tool refresh faster and it is more smooth and not "slow", but something is still wrong with my sample rate. Any idea how to figure out my sample rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `sys.stdout.flush()` as the last line in your for loop, like so:

```
 import sys

 ...

 for i in range(0,10):
    j=i*4
    print str((d[j]/4096.0*5.0)) + ',' 
    print str((d[j+1]-4096)/4096.0*5.0) + ','
    print str(d[j+2]/4096.0*5.0) + ','
    print str((d[j+3]-4096)/4096.0*5.0) + ','
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

what is "very slow"?

> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-FTT86COK', 9600, bytesize=8, timeout=None)

Remember, your input baud rate is 9600, so you're only getting 9600 bytes per second.

You seem to use a complex short integer format, i.e. your sample has 4 bytes.

So you get a 9600/4 = 2400 complex samples per second at most, through your serial interface.

But: for some reason, you seem to skip half of your samples (what about `j+2` and `j+3`? Also, `i=0` is not necessary; that's not how Python `for` loops or `range` work):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    j=i*4
    print str((d[j]/4096.0*5.0)) + ',' 
    print str((d[j+1]-4096)/4096.0*5.0) + ','
```

So that leaves you with 1200 complex samples per second leaving your script *at most*.

```
baudline -reset -samplerate 96000 -channels 2 -quadrature -stdin
```

There's quite some things wrong with this:

- `-samplerate` obviously can't reflect what comes in through your serial line
- `-channels 2` implies that these 1200 samples per second belong to two different channels, so that's 600 S/s per channel.

I don't know which FFT size you're using, but let's go with the (for radar purposes) rather conservative value of 1024; this means you get one transform worth of data roughly every 1.6 s.

So, I don't think there's anything wrong with baudline; you might not have thought your script through, mathematically.

Also: Radar with a 600 Hz bandwidth? Are you sure? What does your radar theory say about the range resolution of a radar system of that bandwidth? (Hint: in my head, a monostatic chirp radar with that bandwidth would have a best-case resolution of 250 thousand kilometers; so, your resolution would be significantly worse than the earth's circumference)

Comment: Yes your correct on all points. I am trying to figure out my sample rate by recording a video of the signal for the time period, then I can count how many samples in that time period. I edited the code to add the other 2 channels. I was able to get baudline to refresh faster by using sys.stdout.flush().